# Optimize.fmin does not find minimum on well-behaved continuous function

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to find the minimum on the following function:

[image: function]

Here's the call:

```
>>> optimize.fmin(residualLambdaMinimize, 0.01, args=(u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended),
                               disp=False, full_output=True, xtol=0.00001, ftol = 0.0001)
Out[19]: (array([ 0.0104]), 0.49331109755304359, 10, 23, 0)
>>> residualLambdaMinimize(0.015, u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended)
Out[22]: 0.46358005517761958
>>> residualLambdaMinimize(0.016, u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended)
Out[23]: 0.42610470795409616
```

As you can see, there's points in the direct neighborhood which yield smaller values. Why doesn't my solver consider them?

Comment: can you give residualLambdaMinimize expression? It is also typically in this kind of hole where the minimization is tricky,bouncing like a ball between two narrow walls and arriving at bottom without really reaching it. The minimization algorithm should be selected accordingly so.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I would have added it here, if there was a quick way of finding a small working sample. It's several layers of function logic, unfortunately.

Comment: All solvers have their good points and their bad points. There is a reason there are so many, after all. But, few will operate flawlessly without some consideration for what they do and how your function impacts what they try to do. Sometimes, a simple thing like rescaling the x-axis will work. Sometimes picking an initial guess far away, but in a 'nice' direction (for the solver) helps. Ultimately, there is something of a black art to finding an 'optimal' solver/system combination.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion which may help you debug the situation.
If you add something like
`data.append((x, result))` to `residualLambdaMinimize`, you can collect all the points where `optimize.fmin` is evaluating `residualLambdaMinimize`:

```
data = []
def residualLambdaMinimize(x, u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended):
    result = ...
    data.append((x, result))
    return result
```

Then we might be better able to understand what `fmin` is doing (and maybe reproduce the problem) if you post `data` without us having to see exactly how `residualLambdaMinimize` is defined.

Moreover, you can visualize the "path" `fmin` is taking as it tries to find the minimum:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []

def residualLambdaMinimize(x, u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended):
    result = (x-0.025)**2
    data.append((x, result))
    return result

u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended = range(4)
retval = optimize.fmin(
    residualLambdaMinimize, 0.01, 
    args=(u, returnsMax, Param, residualLambdaExtended),
    disp=False, full_output=True, xtol=0.00001, ftol = 0.0001)

data = np.squeeze(data)
x, y = data.T
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]